# Using longblob in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I'm new to the hibernate world and I am using it to map a table that stores files of all types. I am however recieving a very strange error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.sql.Blob
```

I have mapped my MySql LONGBLOB column has: `<property name="fileData" type="blob" .../>` and `<property name="fileData" type="longblog" .../>` but both don't work.

I'm currently using spring mvc version 3.x the latest version and tomcant 7 if that helps.

edit: here is how my POJO looks like for fileObject:

package com.kc.models;

public class FileObject {

```
private String fileName;
private String type;
private double size;
private byte[] file;
private int id;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}
public void setFileName(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}
public String getType() {
    return type;
}
public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}
public double getSize() {
    return size;
}
public void setSize(double size) {
    this.size = size;
}
public byte[] getFile() {
    return file;
}
public void setFile(byte[] file) {
    this.file = file;
}
```

}

And here is how my hbm.xml file looks like:

```
<class name="com.kc.models.FileObject" table="FILES">
    <id name="id" column="ID">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="fileName" type="string" column="FILENAME" />
    <property name="type" type="string" column="TYPE" />
    <property name="size" type="double" column="SIZE" />
    <property name="file" type="blob" column="FILE" />
</class>
```

O and here is a print screen of mySql:  http://img412.imageshack.us/img412/3663/fileobject.jpg

Comment: What is the type of `fileData`? Can you show the mapped class?

Comment: <class name="com.kc.models.FileObject" table="FILES">
  <id name="id" column="ID">
   <generator class="native" />
  </id>
  <property name="fileName" type="string" column="FILENAME" />
  <property name="type" type="string" column="TYPE" />
  <property name="size" type="double" column="SIZE" />
  <property name="file" type="blob" column="FILE" />
 </class>

Comment: the property name of file doesnt work

Answer (score 3):

The exception message says that you are trying to cast a `byte[]` (represented as `[B` ) to a `java.sql.Blob`:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.sql.Blob
```

The problem seems to be that while you have defined the POJO property file as a `byte[]`, you are mapping it as an `java.sql.Blob' at Hibernate mapping.

Try to change the property type at the POJO:

```
package com.kc.models;
public class FileObject {
    //...
    private java.sql.Blob file;
    //...
}
```

Comment: http://i-proving.ca/space/Technologies/Hibernate/Blobs+and+Hibernate - example of converting Blob to byte[] and byte[] to Blob.

Comment: Can i still write byte arrays in a java.sql.Blob and does it have a limited size? the reason why i defined a longblob in mysql is so i can store large files and i have heard the default "blog" doesnt store much bytes.

Comment: @jonney: check the useful link provided by MarrLiss. There you'll find how you can handle the conversion between Blob an byte[]. The java.sql.Blob interface API doesn't define any size limit. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html

Comment: cool ok maybe i can just try using java.sql.blob instead of a byte array or copy and paste the code from the link but it says how if your ready a large file, it will affect your RAM.

Comment: I WILL REPORT BACK WITH RESULTS THANKS MAN

Comment: tried the example and i still recieved the same exception so i simply changed the file type from byte[] to Blog and now i am getting a different exception complaining that the data i am trying to add for field FILE is too long?? the files im trying to add are simple image files so none are larger than 2mb at best

Comment: @jonney: try setting a length value at the property mapping (seen here: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2348819&sid=37787cc0dda8f24e149ccf8a57c41ef6#p2348819 )

Answer (score 0):

Try making sure you use @Access(FIELD) for some odd reason running on the JaveSE environment (i.e. JUnit test) and JaveEE environment (e.g. Glassfish) I get different results but it was made consistent when I added the @Access annotation.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Blob getFile() {
    return Hibernate.createBlob(file);
}
```

Comment: You should give a little more information about what your code does.